# Nested form with values from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a workout model:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :time
   belongs_to :user

   has_and_belongs_to_many :trainers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :trainers
end
```

And a trainer model:

```
class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name

    validates_uniqueness_of :name

    has_and_belongs_to_many :workouts

end
```

I need to have a nester trainer form, which allows to pull values from database.
Now I have this inside a new workout form:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :trainers do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.select :trainer, options_for_select(Trainer.all.collect{ |u| [u.name,     u.id] }) %> 
  <br>
<% end %>
```

I get "undefined method `trainer' for #"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to instantiate a trainer otherwise it's an empty relation, so in your controller: @workout.trainers.build. Also, options_from_collection_for_select(Trainer.all, :id, :name)

Comment: I already have code for building in my controller.

Comment: options_from_collection_for_select doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add  attr_accessible  :trainers_attributes to Workout controller